# How to put and include CSS and Javascript libraries in Zend Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zend-framework

I have a big project and many css/less/JQuery files. and i need to include some of them in the layout and other I have to call it in action.

What is the best way to put libraries in zend layout Plus i have to minify scripts ?

shall i create a class or library for that ?

Answer (score 0):

In layout (phtml) you put css/js files that u need in all views (views which used this layout). In view files you include js which will be used only in this view.
In production code u should minify your css/js files.
If your project is big you can create in main js/css folder subfolders for each controller or even action.

Answer (score 0):

I add files using view helper. First i add files when needed:

```
$this->headScript()
            ->prependFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
```

and:

```
$this->inlineScript()
            ->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js')
```

Then i add `<?=$this->headScript()?>` in header and `<?= $this->inlineScript() ?>` before closing body tag.
This will not connect or/and minify your CSS/JS, and i think there is no standard ZF classes which can help you.

If you need something more than you need some work. I haven't tried myself, but friend mentioned [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) is good and easy to [implement](http://web-application.blog.fr/2013/03/31/zend-framework-minify-javascript-js-and-stylesheet-css-files-15698577/) .

You can also install Google Page Speed addon for your server and it has options to minify those files ([here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-css-rewrite?csw=1) and [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-minify?csw=1)).

Last option is to use [YUI Compressor](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/) as shell script, but i think it's too much work.